# list only one Process by name in htop (even when it restarts?)

Tags: bash, htop

i am trying to get htop to show me one process.
this is a programm i wrote wich comes up from time to time (so it always has another pid).
what i am trying is something like that:

```
htop -p $(pgrep execute_extrusion | paste -s -d,)
```

but since the programm execute_extrusion does not run always it does not work like that.
so ideally if not running htop should show an empty list. when running there should be my process (or processes because it can run in parallel multiple times...)

any idea would be great!! thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to monitor your process in `htop` why not simply use the filter by pressing F3 and typing in the name of your executable?